# Convert object of Class into Map

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a class, full of String like

```
data class TestClass (
var par1: String?,
var par2: String?,
var par3: String?
)
```

And I want to convert it to Map, where Key and Value are String. What is the best way to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: Which properties are you trying to convert to a map? Please elaborate on your questions as it is not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Kotlin reflection to implement that, add the `kotlin-reflect` library to the application classpath and use code like that:

```
fun TestClass.asMap() = this::class.declaredMemberProperties
        .map {
          it as KProperty1<TestClass, Any?>
          it.name to it.get(this).toString()
        }.toMap()
```

We cast the `declaredMemberProperties` element from a star-projection to a type with `Any?` instead. The case is unchecked because of the JVM types erasure, but it is still required.